# ConcurrentModificationException on Game Loop on Iterator.next()

Tags: java, android

I am struggling to get this issue sorted on a game loop I have running.

I have the following in my Update() procedure one one thread:

```js
ListIterator<ExplosionClass> litr = Explosions.listIterator();
   while(litr.hasNext()){
          ExplosionClass element = (ExplosionClass) litr.next();
    if (element.FinishedExplosion) {
     litr.remove();
    }
   }
```

I get a ConcurrentModificationException intermittently on litr.next();

I am adding new items to the Explosions list from time to time through another procedure.

My Game loop on the second thread is as follows:

```js
public  void run() {
  Canvas canvas;
  Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");

  long beginTime;  // the time when the cycle begun
  long timeDiff;  // the time it took for the cycle to execute
  int sleepTime;  // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
  int framesSkipped; // number of frames being skipped 

  sleepTime = 0;
  
  // render state to the screen
  // draws the canvas on the panel
  
  while (running) {
  //while (!paused && running) {
   canvas = null;
   synchronized (this) {
                while (isPaused) {
                    try {
                        try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                 this.gamePanel.render(canvas);    
                            }
                            } finally {
                                if (canvas != null) {
                     surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                                }
                        }
                        
                        this.wait();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
   // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
   // in the surface
   try {
    canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
     beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     framesSkipped = 0; // resetting the frames skipped
     // update game state 
     if (!isPaused && running) this.gamePanel.update();
                    
     // render state to the screen
     // draws the canvas on the panel
     if (!isPaused) this.gamePanel.render(canvas);    
     // calculate how long did the cycle take
     timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
     // calculate sleep time
     sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);
     
     if (sleepTime > 0) {
      // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
      try {
       // send the thread to sleep for a short period
       // very useful for battery saving
       Thread.sleep(sleepTime); 
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
     }
     
     while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
      // we need to catch up
      // update without rendering
      if (!isPaused && running) this.gamePanel.update(); 
      // add frame period to check if in next frame
      sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD; 
      framesSkipped++;
     }
    }
   } finally {
    // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
    // an inconsistent state
    if (canvas != null) {
     surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
   } // end finally
  } 
  
  try {
   Thread.sleep(FRAME_PERIOD);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
 //}  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you cannot do that: you have to make sure the other thread isn't changing the list while you are iterating on it using the iterator, use synchronized or some other locking mechanism.

Comment: Hi, I understand this, but looking at the code snippet, is it possible to see where I am not synchronising it correctly?

Comment: As far as I can see the litr is not used in a synchronised section, it should be. In the second snippet I don't see Explosions referenced, so I can't see which monitor you should synchronise on. I also have the impression that Explosions is a variable, not a class, so it shouldn't start with a capital.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, If two iterators simultaneously modify the internal structure of a Collection causes ConcurrentModification Exception. To deal with this use **Synchronised Collections (CopyOnWriteArrayList)**

Answer (score 0):

When you have called a iterator on a list you cannot modify it  when the iterator is doing work.